# debian networking sets wrong ip

Tags: networking, debian, beagleboneblack

I'm currently trying to automate our beaglebone flashing - therefore we have to manually change the ip address.
I created a script which basically adds sth. like:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address theip
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway gateway
```

to /etc/network/interfaces

After adding this I restart networking via:

```
service networking restart
```

Which returns "ok", but ifconfig doesn't return "theip" it seems like it just ignores the changes and still uses dhcp.

When rebooting the system, the ip is changed and everything works as expected, but I don't want to restart the system. So how do I correctly restart the networking?

Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `ip addr flush dev eth0` first and then restart the networking service.

#### Explanation

The /etc/network/interfaces file is used by the ifupdown system. This is different than the graphical NetworkManager system that manages the network by default.
When you add lines to control eth0 in the /etc/network/interfaces file, most graphical network managers assume you are now using the ifupdown service for that interface and drops the option to manage it.

The ifupdown system is less complicated and less sophisticated. Since eth0 is new to the ifupdown system, it assumes that it is unconfigured and tries to "add" the specified address using the `ip` command. Since the interface already has an ip address assigned by dhclient for that network, I suspect it is erroring out. You then need to put the interface in a known state for ifupdown to be able to start managing it. That is without an address assigned to the interface via the ip command.

Comment: After running `ip addr flush dev eth0`, it will leave the computer without network access. Don't do this over ssh